# How should I connect two lighting switches in a double-gang box?

Tags: wiring

For my current project I am attempting to install a single pole dimmer switch alongside a 3 pole dimmer switch. The single pole controls a set of sconces on the wall while the 3 controls the ceiling lights and travels to other things. I am not sure how to go about it though with so many cables in the box. In the photo below, you will see 5 cables in the box.

top of the box 
- (left) hot coming from breaker
- (right) going to high hats in ceiling

bottom of the box (in no specific order because not certain)
- go out to a switch which controls deck lights
- laundry room switch controlling ceiling lights
- garage ceiling lights
-- i know these because these items do not work when wiring is undone and power turned on from breaker.

As you can see below too, I've gone ahead and made sure all ground connections were made.

let me know if any other information is necessary for proper guidance.

[image: image 1 of wiring coming from box]
[image: dimmers being used]
[image: overall setup so far]

Comment: Where is the cable to the sconce?   Also, what do you mean by "3 pole dimmer switch", do you intend to control this light in two places?

Comment: Just a few questions: Why is there a piece of red tape on the power cable hot wire? Why is the power cable neutral wire not nutted in with all the other neutrals? What do you mean by the 3-pole "...travels to other things"? Where is the cable leading to the set of sconces on the wall? Why are you using a 3-pole dimmer?

Comment: @Harper Not sure about the cable to sconce

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri red tape is on the hot wire coming from breaker panel. should all the whites be nutted? 3 pole dimmer because i need the traveler from the wires on the bottom that go out to themisc things?

Comment: Is one of the "misc things" the wall sconces?

Comment: How was the 3-wire dimmer connected before you took everything apart?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Yes, I believe so. & I do not know how it was wired before, This is a newly acquired house and these came like so. The only thing that was wired in there was the 3 pole dimmer with the hot connected to the black, and the red connected to the black wire leading to the ceiling lights and the ground. the other red off the dimmer was capped. with this set up, the ceiling lights works and the laundry room lights, garage lights, and deck lights, and sconces did not.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri see below comments please

Comment: Okay then my diagram was all wrong. You need to make a complete analysis of all the cables -- where do they go and what are they connected to.

Comment: You can't just try hooking up wires any old way until something sort of works. My diagram was based on what you said the cables are but that was obviously wrong. Please *unaccept* my answer so I can delete it. I will answer properly when you have identified all your cables.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I have tested with a multimeter though and confirmed that the mains power feed is the cable in the upper left just as you've put on your diagram. the black cable is the only one that gives any positive voltage reading when all cables are disconnected and tested one by one while the breaker is on.

Comment: So, where is the neutral path back to the circuit breaker? Also, where does the white wire in the upper left cable go? - If the white wire trips the breaker when you try to use it, the neutral return path must be somewhere else. This is sure to be a code violation.